# It is possible to call trigger with old, or new in procedure?

Tags: sql, plsql

I want to insert data using procedure. At first I wanna insert match, but id for football match is generated automatically using trigger. Secondly I want use this id for other table - stats_footballmatch_club. It is possible?

```
INSERT INTO FootballMatch(FootballMatch_Date, Stadium_Id, Tournament_Id) VALUES(TO_DATE('02-04-22','DD-MM-YY'), 1, 1);
INSERT INTO STATS_FOOTBALLMATCH_CLUB(FootballMatch_Id, Club_Id , Goals, Shots, BallControl, Pass) VALUES (1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
INSERT INTO STATS_FOOTBALLMATCH_CLUB(FootballMatch_Id, Club_Id , Goals, Shots, BallControl, Pass) VALUES (1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

If for example, my trigger name is FOOTBALLMATCHTRIGGER, can I do something like that?

```
INSERT INTO STATS_FOOTBALLMATCH_CLUB(FootballMatch_Id, Club_Id , Goals, Shots, BallControl, Pass) VALUES (FOOTBALLMATCHTRIGGER:new, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

This is the footballmatchtrigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER FootballMatchTrigger
BEFORE INSERT 
ON FootballMatch
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    if :NEW.FootballMatch_Id is null then
        SELECT FootballMatchIdSequence.NEXTVAL
        INTO :new.FootballMatch_Id
        FROM dual;
    end if;
END;
```

And there is footballmatch table:

```
CREATE TABLE FootballMatch(
    FootballMatch_Id NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    FootballMatch_Date DATE,
    Stadium_Id NUMBER(4) REFERENCES Stadium(Stadium_Id)  on delete cascade,
    Tournament_Id NUMBER(4) REFERENCES Tournament(Tournament_Id)  on delete cascade
);
```

It also refers to other tables like stadium, and tournament.

Comment: just replace `FOOTBALLMATCHTRIGGER:new` with `:new.id` ( considering the trigger is on `FootballMatch` table and you're joining the tables by matching `id` of `FootballMatch` and `FootballMatch_Id` of `STATS_FOOTBALLMATCH_CLUB`)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan then I get an error: Error at line 57: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.ID' Error at line 56: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.ID'

Comment: Can you edit the question by How you created the trigger? And can you describe the table `FootballMatch` while editing please ...

Comment: Added, there is table above.

Comment: Based on your last edit;  replace `FOOTBALLMATCHTRIGGER:new` with `:new.FootballMatch_Id`. Btw, using `:new.FootballMatch_Id:=FootballMatchIdSequence.nextval;` rather than selecting from dual. Moreover I wonder if the version of the DB is 11g? And `if :NEW.FootballMatch_Id is null then` comparison seems like superflous, you can rather define a primary-foreign key relationship.

Comment: If you want to let the trigger assign the `FootballMatch_Id` value, you can always get it from your `insert` statement by using a `returning...into...` clause.

Comment: If OP wants to do by using `returning...into...` clause, then that should be found out **without** trigger @GriffeyDog

Comment: Edited, and again I get an error: Error at line 57: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.FOOTBALLMATCH_ID' Error at line 56: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.FOOTBALLMATCH_ID'

Comment: Are you sure that the table `FootballMatch` has `FootballMatch_Id` column or the quoted one(such as `"FootballMatch_Id"`) ..? Btw, What's the version of the DB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no you cannot use a trigger for that. A trigger cannot be referenced in code.

Solution: Use the `RETURNING INTO` clause.

Simplified example:

```
DROP TABLE stats_footballmatch_club;
DROP TABLE footballmatch;
DROP SEQUENCE footballmatch_s;

CREATE TABLE footballmatch(
    footballmatch_id NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    footballmatch_date DATE
);

CREATE SEQUENCE footballmatch_s;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER footballmatch_bi BEFORE
  INSERT ON footballmatch
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.footballmatch_id := footballmatch_s.nextval;
END footballmatch_bi;
/

CREATE TABLE stats_footballmatch_club(
    stats_id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    goals NUMBER,
    club VARCHAR2(100),
    footballmatch_id NUMBER(4) REFERENCES footballmatch(footballmatch_id)  on delete cascade
);

DECLARE
  l_footballmatch_id footballmatch.footballmatch_id%TYPE;
BEGIN
INSERT INTO footballmatch(footballmatch_date) VALUES(TO_DATE('02-04-22','DD-MM-YY'))
  RETURNING footballmatch_id INTO l_footballmatch_id;
INSERT INTO stats_footballmatch_club (footballmatch_id, goals, club) VALUES (l_footballmatch_id,3, 'Real Madrid');
INSERT INTO stats_footballmatch_club (footballmatch_id, goals, club) VALUES (l_footballmatch_id,2, 'PSG');
END;
/
```

Notes:

- No need for `SELECT INTO` to assign sequence.NEXTVAL. Just assign using `:= sequence.NEXTVAL`
- Don't even need the trigger for primary key - identity columns are a lot handier ( see table stats_footballmatch_club primary key)